# Как вывести запрос SQL с помощью union в одну строку (выводит в две)?

Tags: oracle, mysql, sql

Нужно вывести в одну строку данные о студенте, подзапрос используется для того, чтобы вывести группу, в которой на данный момент судент учится (в базе отображаются все оценки и группы в которых учился студент) - data_oz - эта дата выставления оценки, во втором select вычисляется средний балл студента. Проблема в том, что выводится в 2 строки =>

```
Иванова Мария Николаевна|БМ-201|128|---

-------------------------------------|----------|-----|3.36
```

Нужно, чтобы 3,36 было в 4 столбце первой строки, не знаю как сделать(

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       FIO "ФИО",
       GRUPPA "Группа",
       ID_FAk "Факультет", 
       null sr
FROM   BI_BALLS
WHERE  data_oz = 
       (SELECT MAX(data_oz)
        FROM   BI_BALLS
        WHERE  ID_STUD=59506
       ) 
and    ID_STUD=59506
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 
       null "ФИО", 
       null "Группа",
       null "Факультет",
       sum(oz_q)/count(oz_q) sr
FROM   BI_BALLS
WHERE  ID_STUD=59506
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT FIO "ФИО",
       GRUPPA "Группа",
       ID_FAk "Факультет", 
       (SELECT avg(oz_q) FROM BI_BALLS t3 WHERE t1.ID_STUD=t3.ID_STUD) sr
FROM   BI_BALLS t1
WHERE  data_oz=
      (SELECT MAX(data_oz)
       FROM   BI_BALLS t2
       WHERE  t1.ID_STUD=t2.ID_STUD) 
and    ID_STUD=59506
```

Answer (score 0):

Так Oracle или MySQL? 
по идее, запрос вообще работать не должен, поскольку во второй строке не хватает условия group by.

А ответ на вопрос - union используется для склеивания строк. Для склеивания колонок используйте join.

Comment: в oracle, просто тут запрос  для обоих вроде должен подойти,я заменил union на join, пишет вообще ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: его не надо "заменять", запрос надо переписать с использованием join. Для начала - почитать, что это такое и как это работает.